# flutter InAppWebView: displaying a local html page

Tags: html, css, flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I am using InAppWebView in my app and trying to display a local html page instead of standard error messages, I have declared the html, css and image I want to use in pupspec.yaml

```
 # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:
      assets:
        - assets/images/error.gif
        - assets/web/error.css
        - assets/web/error.html
```

the loadHtmlFromAssets () function is responsible for calling the local page in onLoadError ()

```
loadHtmlFromAssets() async {

    String htmlFile = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/web/error.html');

    setState(() {
      this._webViewController.loadUrl(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.dataFromString(htmlFile,mimeType: 'text/html',encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"))));
    });

  }
```

the problem is that the html file is displayed without the css or the image, whereas on a normal browser the web page is displayed correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8PK3.png)

can someone help me?